How to get chatbot message logs from Azure bot
Currently I have an Azure bot (echo bot (python   Azure bot farmwork based )), which works perfectly in Teams channel and in web test.

Tried to query from logs no result,  Application insight was connected.
Any queries? Any other options? like to connect to logstream
 from the configuration part only Messaging endpoint is configured and I can see the Application ID
tried the query

In the configuration part, you can see the Instrumentation key from here and Application ID and API key from here there is no confusion.


Any other options? like to connect to logstream


Firstly, you need to Re-check the configuration of application insights to you bot service.



One-thing remember that the logs you're trying to query are being captured and stored in Application Insights. If you're unsure, you might need to adjust the logging configuration in the bot code.

Query:
dependencies
|where timestamp > ago(1h)
|order by timestamp asc



Hi dear Suresh thank you for reaching out , seems the core issues that I just created an application insight for my azure bot but not configured properly . Is there any instruction how to configure it ?)

I have tried your suggested query. received an error

as you said  adjusting  the logging configuration in the bot code should be the best approach but how to do it ? any reference links would be appreciated

Please check this link to configure application insights to the bot code.

I have installed the library to my environment and modified the python code `from botbuilder.core import ActivityHandler, TurnContext import logging from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler
Create a logger object
logger = logging.getLogger(name)
Configure Azure Log Handler with your instrumentation key
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(connection_string='InstrumentationKey=key'))
Set the logging level
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)`
Configured Azure bot with Application insights but still no logs (

Resolved the with another approach. tunneled my azure bot endpoint over local  ngrok  and in the inspector saw all the get post messages thank you for your suggestions  Suresh Chikkam
